# setHours() is always sets the date-time with a delay of my Timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, datetime

Consider the date generator :

```
getStartAndEndDatesByWeeks = howManyWeeksFromNow => {

    let firstDay = new Date();
    let nextWeek = new Date(firstDay.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    let first = nextWeek.getDate() - nextWeek.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    let last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

    let firstday = new Date(nextWeek.setDate(first));
    firstday.setDate(firstday.getDate() + howManyWeeksFromNow * 7);

    let lastday = new Date(nextWeek.setDate(last));
    lastday.setDate(lastday.getDate() + howManyWeeksFromNow * 7);

    firstday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1);
    lastday.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

    return {
      firstday,  // this one is mapped to LeadStartDate
      lastday    // this one is mapped to LeadEndDate
    };
  };
```

It creates the beginning and end of X weeks from now , starting from Sunday.

For example :

Beginning of next week 01/12/19  - 07/12/19

[image]

However when inserting those two fields into Mongo DB, there is a delay of two hours because of my timezone : `(GMT+2)`

Which also leads to a delay of 1 day in the dates (instead of 01/12/19  - 07/12/19  , it's 30/11/19 - 07/12/19)

Even though I set the hours here :

```
   firstday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1);
   lastday.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
```

How can we fix the hours to start without UTC , but with local time :

from `00:01` for firstday / LeadStartDate , and `23:59` for lastday / LeadEndDate

Please notice : I need to store those dates as a date object , not a string.

Thanks

Comment: How do you insert and what is in the db? https://repl.it/repls/MountainousPhysicalQueryplan is quite consistent with your screenshot. 01/12/19 midnight in Jerusalem is 30/11/19 10pm in London. When I insert them in mongo they become `ISODate("2019-11-30T22:00:00.001Z")` and `ISODate("2019-12-07T21:59:59.999Z")`

Comment: Date objects are UTC, you can't change that. They also inherently include a time component. So while you can set the time to 00:00:00 in either UTC or local time, as soon as you apply a different timezone offset, the time won't be zero any more and the date may change too (as you've discovered going from local +2 to UTC +0).

Comment: I would recommend to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) which provides all such functions on the fly. For example you can control DST transition by using either `m.add(7, 'days')` or `m.add(7*24, 'hours')`